# Moving a camera

Tags: vb.net

I have a camera in my 3D game. I have a start vector and and end vector for its positioning. I am wanting to move it smoothly from the first vector to the end vector.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Many more details are needed before anyone will be able to give you a useful response.

Comment: What have you tried? How were the results not what you expected or desired?

Comment: The basic approach would be that you have a timer which draws the scene, moves the camera etc. every x milliseconds. I'm sure you can find good tutorials on Google on this topic.

Comment: OK, the fact that it is a camera is kinda irrelevant. Basically, I am after some code to move from one coordinate to another in a smooth manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do that: StartVector + EndVector * StepValue

Now, you have to decide the step you want to follow (StepValue), and ofcourse you have to put this in a timer in order to control the speed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide what kind of movement you want to have — do you want it to get there at linear speed, or with some smoothing?

If we're talking frame-by-frame movements, I like to use a damping mechanism along the lines of (psuedo-code!):

```
NewPos = CurrentPos + (TargetPos - CurrentPos) * 0.8f;
```

If however you wanted to do it at a fixed rate over a certain time, you'd do something like this each frame:

```
NewPos = CurrentPos + ((TargetPos - StartPos) / (DesiredTime * FrameRate));
```

Of course, you'd want to just do the calculation once, store the result in another vector and just add that to your position each frame.